# Import qbxml file into Quickbook - Desktop

Tags: python, quickbooks, qbxml

I am working on a Django/Python project, which include the integration of the Quick book payment, I am using mysql database for storing records,
Now with my code I am able to create a complete qbxml file succesfully for sales recipt.
I want to import that file/data in quickbook-desktop to generate sales reciepts.    **I just need some-one to guide me how to import data of the qbxml into quickbook-desktop pro**

This is the qbxml file generated

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="4.0"?>
<QBXML>
 <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">

  <SalesReceiptAddRq requestID="100004">
   <SalesReceiptAdd>
    <CustomerRef>
     <FullName>(Web)</FullName>
    </CustomerRef>
    <TemplateRef>
     <FullName>Web Sales Receipt</FullName>
    </TemplateRef>
    <TxnDate>Aug. 6, 2019</TxnDate>
    <RefNumber>I-100004</RefNumber>



        <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
         <ItemRef>
          <FullName>Palm Tree</FullName>
         </ItemRef>
         <Desc>Moon Necklace</Desc>
         <Quantity>3</Quantity>
         <Rate>1.00</Rate>
         <Amount>3.00</Amount>
         <SalesTaxCodeRef>
          <FullName>Tax</FullName>
         </SalesTaxCodeRef>
        </SalesReceiptLineAdd>

        <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
         <ItemRef>
          <FullName>Sun Face</FullName>
         </ItemRef>
         <Desc>Moon Necklace</Desc>
         <Quantity>4</Quantity>
         <Rate>1.00</Rate>
         <Amount>3.00</Amount>
         <SalesTaxCodeRef>
          <FullName>Tax</FullName>
         </SalesTaxCodeRef>
        </SalesReceiptLineAdd>


    <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
     <!-- blank line -->
    </SalesReceiptLineAdd>

    <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
      <ItemRef>
       <FullName>Shipping</FullName>
      </ItemRef>
      <Desc>Shipping and handling</Desc>
      <Amount>4.5 </Amount>
      <SalesTaxCodeRef>
       <FullName>Non</FullName>
      </SalesTaxCodeRef>
    </SalesReceiptLineAdd>

    <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
     <!-- blank line -->
    </SalesReceiptLineAdd>

    <SalesReceiptLineAdd>
     <Desc>11.5 was charged to a credit card</Desc>
    </SalesReceiptLineAdd>

   </SalesReceiptAdd>
  </SalesReceiptAddRq>
```

I want to import my generated qbxml file into quickbook-desktop to generate sales

Answer (score 0):

This is more complicated than it should be. You need to use the Quickbooks Web Connector.  That requires installing a Soap server that goes between you and the desktop Quickbooks. Something similar to [this](https://github.com/DanHanson82/quickbooks-desktop-python) or [this](https://github.com/RappidDevelopment/quickbooks-js) is what you need.